# How to access today button in FullCalendar React, or how to add a callback function to the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, fullcalendar

How can I access the fullCalendar "today" button in React? e.g. How can I apply callback functions on it?

Below is my FullCalendar component.

```
<FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionGridPlugin]}
          initialView={'dayGridMonth'}
          headerToolbar={{
            start: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'today prev,next',
          }}
          height={'80vh'}
          handleWindowResize={true}
        />
```

[image]

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('my-today-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  calendar.today();
});
```

but this will not work in React.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct callback for this button specifically as far as I know. It's useful to realise that all the button does is execute fullCalendar's [today](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-today) function.

In common with all the other date navigation functions and triggers, this will cause the [datesSet](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) callback to run. You can use that callback to see what date the calendar has been set to, and whether that matches today's date. That way you can detect whenever the calendar is moved to today's date, whether that's done via the button or some other method.

Note that because most of the calendar's views display a range of dates, the callback returns the start and end of the range. Therefore you'll need to calculate whether the today's date falls within that range, rather than doing a simple match.

e.g.

```
datesSet: function( dateInfo ) {
  console.log(dateInfo.startStr, dateInfo.endStr);
  var today = new Date();
  if (today >= dateInfo.start && today < dateInfo.end)
    {
      console.log("Today's date is being shown");
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoLBevB

Relevant documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation